# DNS manager in Windows Server 2012 Essentials - My one server appears twice

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2012

I have a newly installed Windows Server 2012 Essentials.

It works pretty good although I'm working on some  [DNS improvements](https://serverfault.com/questions/604157/bind-as-secondary-dns-to-windows-server-2012-windows-complains-that-bind-is-no).

Something that seems a little weird is in DNS Manager, my server appears twice. Once as hostname and once as hostname.mydomain.local. They seem to be identical and locked in sync. If I change one, the other follows. Is this normal? Does anyone know why I have this? I'm talking about the top level on the navigation. The very top is DNS and then these two below. Zones, forwarders etc are below them.

I've found a couple of forum posts of people asking the same thing but no useful answer. All tutorials etc I can find with screenshots show only one which makes me uncomfortable.

The server was installed out of the box using the wizards. I know about the recommendation not to use .local but the wizards didn't give me any other option.

Comment: Got a quick screenshot you could put up here?  I'm 99% sure of what you're saying I just want to be **100%.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DNS Manager MMC can manage multiple servers from the same console; you have the option to connect to as many servers as you like (assuming you have the necessary permissions to manage them); it will remember the servers it was connected to when last closed, and it will automatically reconnect to all of them upon reopening it.

You can connect to a DNS server using its IP address, host name or FQDN; this allows you to open multiple connections to the same server and to have it appear on the console multiple times, which of course is quite useless.

To fix this, simply right-click on one of the two servers and select the option to remove it; it will disappear from the console, but this will not affect in any way its configuration.

Comment: That makes perfect sense, thanks. I was worried it was something more complicated or messy. Similar to SQL Management Studio.

Answer (score 0):

As for why the server is listed twice, I have no idea.

As for what to do about it, you can delete one instance of it from the console (it shouldn't matter which one). This `WILL NOT` remove the DNS role or affect DNS in any way. It will simply remove the server from the DNS Management console.

Once you've removed one instance from the DNS Management console close and reopen the console and see if it remains with one instance or if both instances are back.