# Microsoft DHCP server and Unix BIND dynamic DNS

Tags: dhcp, bind, dynamic-dns

Is there any way to make Microsoft DHCP server to securely dynamically update A and PTR records in Unix Bind DNS zone?

Microsoft supports secure update using username/password authentication. Bind9 support secure update using keys. But I couldn't find the way to make Microsoft DHCP to use key as it can be done with dhcpd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not securely.

You might be able to have a single Microsoft DNS server and then do some kind of zone transfer between that and BIND?

These links may or may not help in that regard:

- https://support.microsoft.com/kb/275866
- https://support.microsoft.com/kb/255913
- [How can I get BIND and Microsoft DNS to work together well?](https://serverfault.com/questions/6273/how-can-i-get-bind-and-microsoft-dns-to-work-together-well)

Comment: It's possible to do with GSS-TSIG (Kerberos).

Comment: Thanks briantist, I've decided to move DNS zone to Microsoft DNS server and it solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I spent some time trying to achieve something similar. In the "allow-update" statement, BIND recognizes two "Microsoft" update sources: ms-self and ms-subdomain.

My task was a temporary solution so I went with vanilla TSIG keys, but if you can get GSS-TSIG working with AD here are some useful links:

http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch7/xfer.html#update-policy

https://lists.isc.org/pipermail/bind-users/2013-April/090301.html